# Using Github Action with Docker and '--privileged'

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

As far as I have understood, there isn't a way to use the '--privileged' flag for a docker container. The problem is, that '--privileged' is needed in order to mount Fuse module. Adding '--cap-add SYS_ADMIN' doesn't do the trick. What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's not available as a standard Github Actions container option, but you can run 'docker --privileged' yourself in a 'run' step.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I did it https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/pull/660

Answer (score 0):

You can put `--privileged` in `options`. [Example](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/commit/f248742153f311a0a540c1deebc7e1d248755e75#diff-a66f3a0ab779cce7ad24e378209d82ac8593ece1a9094bb770fdd4d25b4c1b31R125).